# Firebase Dynamic Link PendingDynamicLinkData return null android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I tried the below firebase official dynamic link sample but is not working for me.

**[Dynamic Link](https://plpsoft.page.link?amv=0&apn=com.google.firebase.quickstart.deeplinks&link=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fdeeplinks):**

**Mainfest:**

```
 <activity android:name=".java.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- [START link_intent_filter] -->
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                    android:host="plpsoft.page.link"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <data
                    android:host="plpsoft.page.link"
                    android:scheme="http"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- [END link_intent_filter] -->
        </activity>
```

**Activity:**

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
                    .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PendingDynamicLinkData> task) {
                            Uri deepLink = null;
                            if (task.getResult() != null) {
                                deepLink=task.getResult().getLink();
                                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.linkViewReceive))
                                        .setText(deepLink.toString());

                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                            // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                            Uri deepLink = null;
                            if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                                deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                            }


                            // Handle the deep link. For example, open the linked
                            // content, or apply promotional credit to the user's
                            // account.
                            // ...

                            // [START_EXCLUDE]
                            // Display deep link in the UI
                            if (deepLink != null) {
                                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                                        "Found deep link!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.linkViewReceive))
                                        .setText(deepLink.toString());
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "getDynamicLink: no link found");
                            }
                            // [END_EXCLUDE]
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Splash", "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                        }
                    });
    }
```

While tapping the URL the app will launch successfully and i get the intent data URI string also. if i pass this URI to **getDynamicLink()** method it's return as null. I also add the both **SHA1** and **SHA256** key in firebase console.

Comment: Getting same error which we extracting the firebase deep link url in Android app. Any one is experienced the same, please help.

Comment: I was only able to get the link using:
Uri link = getIntent().getData()
Unsuccessful with:
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(getIntent())

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by removing the intent-filter from the manifest and adding the callback handler in the MainActivity.

What the docs says is that:

*In the callback the PendingDynamicLinkData  is returned in addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener) or addOnCompleteListener(Activity, OnCompleteListener) which returns the most recently clicked dynamic link, or null if a dynamic link was not pending as captured data or in the intent.*

So the deeplink was being captured by the intent filter and because it was not longer pending the callback returns null